# Elm no data except isTrusted in JSON events

Tags: elm

I wrote a simple program based on [time example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/time), to test what data are  in events. It decodes JSON to value then encodes it back to JSON, then show it in SVG text element. And the only thing I get is `{"isTrusted":true}`.

Why that happens? How do I get another data of event? I'm using Firefox 49 and [online compiler](http://elm-lang.org/examples/time):

```
import Html exposing (Html)
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)
import Svg.Events exposing(on)
import Json.Decode as Json
import Json.Encode exposing (encode)

main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- MODEL
type alias Model = String

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  ("No event", Cmd.none)


-- UPDATE
type Msg
  = Event String

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Event event ->
      (event, Cmd.none)


subscriptions model = Sub.none


stringifyEvent: Json.Encode.Value -> Msg
stringifyEvent x = 
  Event (encode 2 x)

-- VIEW

view : Model -> Svg Msg
view model =
    svg [ viewBox "0 0 300 300", width "300px", on "mousedown" (Json.map stringifyEvent Json.value) ] [ 
       text_ [x "0", y "30"] [text model]
    ]
```

When I try in console

```
svgElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(e)})
```

It works with all the attributes.

Comment: Did you find a solution this? I'm getting it on regular html elements.

Comment: No, I guess I should have some different way to debug.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know a way to achieve your goal.
But I can give you an answer why it does the way you described.

If you look at the source code, you'll find that Elm runtime uses
`JSON.stringify()` for converting `Value` to `String`.

And guess what...
`svgElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(JSON.stringify(e))})`
will give you `{"isTrusted":true}` when you click...

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Tosh, the data is not correctly passed through for some events (e.g. also for `CustomEvent`).

However, there is an easy workaround by simply (mis)using only predefined events, for which it works correctly. A full list is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#interfaces_based_on_event).

One that's especially suited ist the [`MessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent). It has a `data` field for holding arbitrary data related to the message.

For your example, where the event type is pre-determined by the HTML element, you could wrap your HTML with a [custom web-component](https://elmprogramming.com/interacting-with-web-components.html), capture the emitted event, and re-emit the event as a MessageEvent.

```js
this.dispatchEvent(
  new MessageEvent(
    "customData",
    {
      data: {"x": 123},
      composed: true,
    }
  )
)
```

```
onCustomData : Attribute Msg
onCustomData toMsg =
    on "customData"
        (JD.field "data" (JD.field "x" JD.int)
            |> JD.map XValueReceived
        )
```